# VirtualBox: Cannot write compressed data block (VERR_DISK_FULL

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, packer

I am trying to export a virtual-machine with packer, and after the installation process process is completed I am prompted the following error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGLAd.png)

My disk is not full - I have 750GB of free space, also I can generate other images with packer just fine.
Can someone explain why this fails? I don't understand whats wrong.

The packer scripts looks like this:

```
{
    "builders": [
      {
        "boot_command": [
          "<esc><esc><f6><esc><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
          "<wait>auto=true priority=critical noprompt ",
          "<wait>automatic-ubiquity ",
          " url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/desktoptestOffice.cfg ",
          " keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us ",
          " ubiquity/reboot=true ",
          " languagechooser/language-name=English ",
          " countrychooser/shortlist=IN ",
          " localechooser/supported-locales=en_US.UTF-8 ",
          " debian-installer/locale=en_US ",
          " netcfg/choose_interface=auto ",
          " boot=casper ",
          " initrd=/casper/initrd ",
          " quiet splash noprompt noshell ",
          " --- <wait>",
          "<enter><wait>"
        ],
        "boot_wait": "6s",
        "disk_size": "40000",
        "export_opts": [
          "--vsys",
          "0",
          "--description",
          "{{user `vm_description`}}",
          "--version",
          "{{user `vm_version`}}"
        ],
        "guest_additions_path": "VBoxGuestAdditions_{{.Version}}.iso",
        "guest_os_type": "Ubuntu_64",
        "headless": "{{user `headless`}}",
        "http_directory": "http",
        "iso_checksum": "{{ user `iso_checksum_type` }}:{{ user `iso_checksum` }}",
        "iso_target_path": "{{ user `iso_target_path` }}",
        "iso_urls": [
          "{{ user `iso_url` }}",
          "iso-packer/ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso"
        ],
        "keep_registered": "{{user `keep_registered`}}",
        "output_directory": "/tmp/pse-test",
        "shutdown_command": "echo 'password1' | sudo -S shutdown -P now",
        "ssh_password": "password1",
        "ssh_port": 22,
        "ssh_timeout": "10000s",
        "ssh_username": "yuyong",
        "type": "virtualbox-iso",
        "vboxmanage": [
          [
            "modifyvm",
            "{{.Name}}",
            "--memory",
            "2048"
          ],
          [
            "modifyvm",
            "{{.Name}}",
            "--cpus",
            "2"
          ]
        ],
        "virtualbox_version_file": ".vbox_version",
        "vm_name": "pse-test",
        "vboxmanage_post": [
          ["modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--nic2", "intnet", "--intnet1", "intnet"],
          ["modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--macaddress2", "a23427226F14"],
          ["modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--nic1", "bridged", "--bridgeadapter1", "enp0s31f6"],
          ["modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--macaddress1", "a23427226F04"]
        ]
      }
    ],
    "description": "Packer template for building ubuntu bionic 18 desktop",
    "provisioners": [
  ],
    "variables": {
      "iso_checksum": "",
      "iso_checksum_type": "md5",
      "iso_target_path": "iso-packer/",
      "iso_url": "",
      "keep_registered": "false",
      "vm_description": "Ubuntu AMD64 Bionic 18 Desktop",
      "vm_version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "post-processors": [
      {
        "type": "shell-local",
        "command": "echo \"1\" > /tmp/pse-test-packer-status"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Also, on a different machine I was told the script works just fine. Any ideas for the root cause of the problem?

Comment: Are you perhaps not directing the output to the disk you intended to? Try using a full path.